# Как пишется "пилатес (?) ретрит"?

Tags: неологизмы

Я бы написала через дефис. Но сомневаюсь. А вообще, есть ли какие-то хорошие справочники с такими неологизмами?

Comment: https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/econ_dict/20355

Comment: йога-ретрит  в статье https://lenta.ru/articles/2023/03/09/retrity/  Ретрит https://kolomonos.ru/blog/pilates-i-chto-eto-dlya-chego-komu-podhodit/

Comment: Правило § 121, пункт 3.  http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=66#pp66

Comment: @Буратино Вы по смыслу связали слова ретрит и тур? Как следование или путешествие? Пытаюсь понять аналогию в вашем комментарии...

Comment: @Sharon Спасибо за ссылки. А к какому пункту из правила в пособии Лопатина можно отнести это слово, как думаете? Сложные слова с несклоняемой первой частью?

Comment: Это  § 121, пункт 3. Существительные, состоящие из двух или более элементов, отдельно в русском языке (в качестве самостоятельных слов либо повторяющихся частей сложных слов) не употребляющихся.

Comment: @Татьяна - ага, я подумал ретрит (перевод уединение), тип путешествия/отдыха, как тур, только уединение. Думаю в экономических словарях можно встретить подобное, но может еще ретрит не добавили. "Ретрит (англ. retreat — «уединение», «удаление от общества») — это время, которое человек посвящает духовным практикам, чаще всего за городом или даже в другой стране."

Comment: Это два нарицательных существительных, одно из них следует считать приложением.  В отдельности каждое слово склоняется, но в сложном слове первая часть склоняться не будет. Такое склонение возможно в составных русских названиях: вагон-ресторан, диван-кровать. У Лопатина такой вид сложных слов отдельно не рассматривается, но мы на слух опредеяем, что первая часть не склоняется.

Comment: И тогда это дефисное написание (золото-старушка, царь-пушка, горе-охотник).

Comment: @Буратино спасибо! Да, аналогия хорошая )

Comment: @Sharon Спасибо!